# Passport and NestJS login not functioning – seeking assistance

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs, passport.js

My problem is, when I'm trying to login, I have this responses :

```
{
    "message": "Unauthorized",
    "statusCode": 401
}
```

when I'm looking in my console.log, I have this :

```
Erreur lors de l'appel à super.canActivate : UnauthorizedException: Unauthorized
    at LocalAuthGuard.handleRequest (/Users/alexscdt/Documents/Extia/Mecenat/Emerga/Emerga-API-NestJS/node_modules/@nestjs/passport/dist/auth.guard.js:60:30)
    at /Users/alexscdt/Documents/Extia/Mecenat/Emerga/Emerga-API-NestJS/node_modules/@nestjs/passport/dist/auth.guard.js:44:124
    at /Users/alexscdt/Documents/Extia/Mecenat/Emerga/Emerga-API-NestJS/node_modules/@nestjs/passport/dist/auth.guard.js:83:24
    at allFailed (/Users/alexscdt/Documents/Extia/Mecenat/Emerga/Emerga-API-NestJS/node_modules/passport/lib/middleware/authenticate.js:110:18)
    at attempt (/Users/alexscdt/Documents/Extia/Mecenat/Emerga/Emerga-API-NestJS/node_modules/passport/lib/middleware/authenticate.js:183:28)
    at LocalStrategy.strategy.fail (/Users/alexscdt/Documents/Extia/Mecenat/Emerga/Emerga-API-NestJS/node_modules/passport/lib/middleware/authenticate.js:314:9)
    at LocalStrategy.Strategy.authenticate (/Users/alexscdt/Documents/Extia/Mecenat/Emerga/Emerga-API-NestJS/node_modules/passport-local/lib/strategy.js:75:17)
    at attempt (/Users/alexscdt/Documents/Extia/Mecenat/Emerga/Emerga-API-NestJS/node_modules/passport/lib/middleware/authenticate.js:378:16)
    at authenticate (/Users/alexscdt/Documents/Extia/Mecenat/Emerga/Emerga-API-NestJS/node_modules/passport/lib/middleware/authenticate.js:379:7)
    at /Users/alexscdt/Documents/Extia/Mecenat/Emerga/Emerga-API-NestJS/node_modules/@nestjs/passport/dist/auth.guard.js:88:3 {
  response: { message: 'Unauthorized', statusCode: 401 },
  status: 401,
  options: {}
}
[Nest] 4023  - 02/07/2024, 11:13:20 AM   ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] Failed to serialize user into session
Error: Failed to serialize user into session
    at pass (/Users/alexscdt/Documents/Extia/Mecenat/Emerga/Emerga-API-NestJS/node_modules/passport/lib/authenticator.js:296:19)
    at serialized (/Users/alexscdt/Documents/Extia/Mecenat/Emerga/Emerga-API-NestJS/node_modules/passport/lib/authenticator.js:301:7)
    at SessionSerializer.serializeUser (/Users/alexscdt/Documents/Extia/Mecenat/Emerga/Emerga-API-NestJS/src/modules/auth/serializers/session.serializer.ts:7:5)
    at /Users/alexscdt/Documents/Extia/Mecenat/Emerga/Emerga-API-NestJS/node_modules/@nestjs/passport/dist/passport/passport.serializer.js:8:61
    at pass (/Users/alexscdt/Documents/Extia/Mecenat/Emerga/Emerga-API-NestJS/node_modules/passport/lib/authenticator.js:309:9)
    at Authenticator.serializeUser (/Users/alexscdt/Documents/Extia/Mecenat/Emerga/Emerga-API-NestJS/node_modules/passport/lib/authenticator.js:314:5)
    at /Users/alexscdt/Documents/Extia/Mecenat/Emerga/Emerga-API-NestJS/node_modules/passport/lib/sessionmanager.js:33:10
    at Immediate.<anonymous> (/Users/alexscdt/Documents/Extia/Mecenat/Emerga/Emerga-API-NestJS/node_modules/express-session/session/store.js:54:5)
    at processImmediate (node:internal/timers:478:21)
```

I share you my code :

users.controller.ts

```
  //post /login
  @UseGuards(LocalAuthGuard)
  @Post('login')
  login(@Request() req): any {
    return { User: req.user, msg: 'User successfully logged in' };
  }
```

local.auth.guard.ts

```
import { ExecutionContext, Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AuthGuard } from '@nestjs/passport';

@Injectable()
export class LocalAuthGuard extends AuthGuard('local') {
  async canActivate(context: ExecutionContext) {
    const result = (await super.canActivate(context)) as boolean;
    const request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
    await super.logIn(request);
    return result;
  }
}
```

session.serializer.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { PassportSerializer } from '@nestjs/passport';

@Injectable()
export class SessionSerializer extends PassportSerializer {
  serializeUser(user: any, done: (err: Error, user: any) => void): any {
    done(null, user);
  }

  deserializeUser(
    payload: any,
    done: (err: Error, payload: string) => void,
  ): any {
    done(null, payload);
  }
}
```

local.strategy.ts

```
import { Injectable, UnauthorizedException } from '@nestjs/common';
import { PassportStrategy } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { Strategy } from 'passport-local';
import { AuthService } from '../auth.service';

@Injectable()
export class LocalStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {
  constructor(private readonly authService: AuthService) {
    super({ usernameField: 'email' });
  }

  async validate(email: string, password: string): Promise<any> {
    const user = await this.authService.validateUser(email, password);
    if (!user) {
      throw new UnauthorizedException();
    }
    return user;
  }
}
```

auth.service.ts

```
import { Injectable, NotAcceptableException } from '@nestjs/common';
import { UsersService } from '../users/users.service';
import * as bcrypt from 'bcrypt';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  constructor(private readonly usersService: UsersService) {}

  async validateUser(email: string, password: string): Promise<any> {
    const user = await this.usersService.findByEmail(email);
    const passwordValid: boolean = await bcrypt.compare(
      password,
      user.password,
    );
    if (!user) {
      throw new NotAcceptableException('could not find the user');
    }

    if (!passwordValid) {
      throw new NotAcceptableException('password is not valid');
    }

    if (user && passwordValid) {
      return {
        userId: user._id,
        email: user.email,
      };
    }

    return null;
  }
}
```

main.ts

```
import * as session from 'express-session';

...

  app.use(
    session({
      secret: 'keyBoard',
      resave: false,
      saveUninitialized: false,
    }),
  );
  app.use(passport.initialize());
  app.use(passport.session());
```

and this my body for login route :

```
{
    "email  ": "email@ygmail.cddqzoem",
    "password": "OUIOUIOUdzdqI"
}
```

I would just like my login to work while keeping the email and password as parameters.